# Change components' state base on mouseEntered and mouseExited

Tags: java, python, json, compiler-errors, cpu-word

I'm a total newbie to Java and trying to learn the GUI Swing framework.

My goal is to create a human face component with eyes open and close - depending on mouse status (enter: eyes open, exit: eyes close)

I'm stuck with the structure and don't know how to connect the face component to a `MouseListener`.

Appreciate any feedback on the code and advice to learn better. Thanks!

Comment: "I'm a total newbie to Java and trying to learn the GUI Swing framework." - that might not be the best combination, especially if you're new to programming in general. If this is the case you should start with the basics first. As for your problem: `MouseListener` etc. would be used to register a listener on a _component_ (like a panel or button) and the framework then calculates whether the mouse entered or left that component. The component itself could be retrieved via the `getSource()` method of the event and casting the return value (this already indicates how _old_ this system is) ...

Comment: ... Since you're not using components but draw the panel yourself you'd need to do the "enter/leave" calculation yourself as well (e.g. use the current mouse position which can be tracked on the panel using a `MouseMotionListener`). Or, what would be better, use actual components, provide a look and feel implementation that allows for round buttons and let the framework do the calculations.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will teach you how to create Swing GUIs.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create one class to do all the custom painting of the face (eyes, nose, mouth, etc).
2. add this panel to the frame.

In this panel you can create two instance variables to represent the eyes:

```
private Shape leftEye = new Rectangle(170, 180, 70, 90);
private Shape rightEye = new Rectangle(320, 180, 70, 90);
```

and two variable to represent the state of each eye:

```
private boolean isLeftEyeOpen;
private boolean isRightEyeOpen;
```

Create methods to update the state of each eye:

```
public void setLeftEyeOpen(boolean isLeftEyeOpen)
{
    this.isLeftEyeOpen = isLeftEyeOpen;
}
```

Add your MouseListener to this panel and listen for the `mouseMoved()` event (not mouseEntered and mouseExited). Then you set the state of each variable:

```
setLeftEyeOpen( leftEye.contains(e.getPoint() );
setRightEyeOpen( rightEye.contains(e.getPoint() );
repaint();
```

Then in the painting code you have:

```
if (isLeftEyeOpen)
    //  paint eye open
else
    //  paint eye closed.
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) for a basic example to help structure your code.